# Decomposition of wave number

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Wave number can be easily obtained in one dimensional situation.
$$k=\omega/c$$
In the book, Fundamentals of Acoustics, the method of **separation of variables** is applied to solve two dimensional wave equation. It follows that wave number is also decomposed.
$$k_x^{2}+k_z^{2}=k^{2}$$
$k_x$ and $k_z$ are determined by the boundary conditions.

But in one dimensional wave equation, it seems that we don't need additional conditions to get wave number. Given a specific frequency $f$ and the velocity $c$ of wave is determined by medium. Then we can get  $k$.

I wonder how to determine the value of the decomposed wave number if there are no boundary conditions, for example, an infinite area. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the explanation in the book [1].

$k_x$ is called the trace wavenumber in the $x$ direction. $\lambda_x=2\pi/k_x$ is called the trace wavelength in the $x$ direction. $c_x=\omega/k_x$ is called the phase speed of the trace wave along the $x$ axis.

Since $k$ is a constant, the trace wavenumbers are not independent of one another. Importantly, there is no restriction on the value of $k_x$ and $k_z$; they can extend over all real numbers from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

If the wave propagates in the direction given by $\theta$, the angle between the direction of propagation and the Z-axis, the trace wavenumbers follow that:
$$k_x =k sin\theta$$
$$k_z =k cos\theta$$

For more imformation, you can read the book.

[1] Earl G. Williams, Fourier Acoustics, Academic Press, 1999, https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-012753960-7/50009-7